# NEXT 13 JS how to fetch data from firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, fetch

I know how to get data from firebase firestore, but I want to use fetch from NEXT.js, "Next.js extends the native fetch Web API to allow you to configure the caching and revalidating behavior for each fetch request on the server. React extends fetch to automatically memoize fetch requests while rendering a React component tree.", I want to use the cache, but I don't know how to use the fetch like this.

```
`async function getData(name:string) {
const data = await getPostsByTag(name); // Here how to get data using fetch
const posts = data;
return {posts};
}
export default async function Categorias({ params }: { params: { name: string } }) {
const receiver = await getData(params.name);
const posts = receiver.posts;
return (
<>
<BarTop value={100} />
  <CategoryData name={params.name} postsData = {posts} />
</>
);
}`
```

How to use fetch using a third pary like firebase